# Character Limit not working inside update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, limit

I'm using Jquery plugin called [Limit](http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/) as below

```
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('[id$=Textarea1]').limit('150', '#charsLeft');
    });
```

Relevant ASPX section,

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
    <textarea id="Textarea1" class ="limit" runat="server" rows="4" cols="30" style="resize: none;
        background-color: #F9E8EC; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" ></textarea>
    <br />
    You have <span id="charsLeft">160</span> chars left.
</td>
```

both above controls are inside update panel. fist time I can see this limit function works fine. but when update panel updated span shows 160 characters and not updating when typing on text area. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the update panel, and `document` `ready` not playing nice. An update panel essentially replaces all content on the page, but as the `document` is already `ready`, the event is never re-triggered.

What you'll want to do is move your `document` `ready` events into a separate function, and then call it both during document ready, and when an update has occurred within an update panel, something like this:

```
function onDocumentReady()
{
    $('[id$=Textarea1]').limit('150', '#charsLeft');
}

// this will get called on the first load
$(function()
{
    onDocumentReady();
});

// this will get called when an update panel request finishes
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(onDocumentReady);
```

### Alternatively (Un-tested)

What you might be able to do is trigger the `ready` event on the `document` when an update panel reloaded, you could try this:

```
// this will get called on the first load
$(function()
{
    $('[id$=Textarea1]').limit('150', '#charsLeft');
});

// this will get called when an update panel request finishes, triggering the dom ready
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(function()
{
    $(document).trigger('ready');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must leave the span empty. The jQuery plugin will fill it itself.

Comment: if I put empty span then, it shows empty when update panel refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Damith I tried your code and it is working completely fine for me. Are you getting any error?

Below is HTML code I am using and JavaScript is same as what you have.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>    
     <textarea id="Textarea1" class ="limit" runat="server" rows="4" cols="30"      style="resize: none; background-color: #F9E8EC; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" ></textarea>
<br />
 You have <span id="charsLeft">160</span> chars left.
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: @Nil , Thanks for the info, no errors but it is not working.. bdw my aspx is more complex and i'm using Chrome as browser. I'm able to fix it with the help of Richard's answer